# Regex for "... FooBar ..."?

Tags: regex

What is regexp to find a quoted `FooBar` in expressions such as:

```
"FooBar"
"Hello, FooBar!"
"Some text, FooBar, some text..."
"garbageFooBarGarbage"
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just `^\".*FooBar.*\"$` should do the work.

Comment: This will also find `"Some" text, FooBar, some "more text..."`

Answer (score 4):

This is a difficult question for regex. If you have a row with two or more quoted parts, how do you know if "FooBar" is quoted or between two other quoted parts?

A solution that gets a bit closer would be this:

```
^[^"\r\n]*(?:"[^"\r\n]*"[^"\r\n]*)*[^"\r\n]*("[^"\r\n]*FooBar[^"\r\n]*")
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vgsk)

It looks at the complete string, `^` is matching the start of the string and then matching the non quotes. `(?:"[^"\r\n]*"[^"\r\n]*)*` this is matching pairs of quotes with the stuff between and following non quote characters. And then follows the  part you want to match `("[^"\r\n]*FooBar[^"\r\n]*")` its in brackets, so you find it in the first capturing group.

I am also ignoring newline characters. If you want to match them at some place just remove the `\r\n` from that character class.

This is all under the assumption that there are no single quotes and no escaped quotes. With single quotes you would be totally lost, and ignoring escaped quotes would be possible, but makes your regex more complex.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! I just asked my question in context of searching a few words in a lot of source code. The answer marked as valid helped me and I agree with you it will also find invalid pattern.

Answer (score -1):

This should work: `/FooBar/g` or `/FooBar/gi` if you want it case-insensitive. (example: http://regexr.com?2vgs2)

Comment: Without them even mentioning a language I usually consider it not very helpful to include language-specific regex literals. If the person asking doesn't know Perl, PHP, or JavaScript they might just notice that this doesn't work.

Comment: What about the quotes?  The match is supposed to be enclosed in quotation marks.

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Comment: Gah! Sorry, I got all excited and hasty.